# Container memory_working_set jumps almost 500MB everyday at same time, but rss remains constant

Tags: kubernetes, memory-leaks, grafana-loki

We are running Grafana Loki on a Kubernetes Cluster and are noticing a strange pattern of increase in memory usage especially of memory_working_set which jumps almost 500MB every day at around 1:00 AM UST time. But the RSS memory remains constant during that period.
[image: Memory Usage]

We have done a lot of research around go pprof, setting different parameters for Loki, etc but are up to no luck. Wanted to understand if anybody has faced similar issues, and how did you get this fixed. We wanted to understand what is causing this kind of spike.

Also noticed one more thing cache memory is very high, its almost around 500MB. Is this the cause of the spike ?

[image: memory status]

Comment: Share your answers to the below questions to understand more about your setup:

What are the processes that are running?
What are the memory utilization and cpu utilization status for each process during the memory spike?
Have you checked system logs for debugging the reason for memory spike?